# R Shiny Create Dynamic Numeric Input Based off Checkboxes

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

The program I'm writing takes a spreadsheet of grades and then creates tables, plots, and summaries of the data it receives. However, I want multiple users to be able to use this. This means the weight of each type of grade (Homework, Tests, Quizzes, etc) will be different for each user.

What I'm trying to do is create a checkboxGroupInput that generates a list of the different types of grades (read from 'Type' column in the spreadsheet), then when each checkbox is checked a numericInput will pop up allowing the user to select a weight. Here is an example picture.

[Example Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RqtR.jpg)
(Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post an image right now)

However, I don't know how to render the numericInput to a True/False value of each checkbox. I know how to render a table to show columns based on group input, like in [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-demo.html), but I don't know how to initiate an unknown number of numericInputs since each one will be its own variable. Is this possible? I can't think of another way to achieve what I want.

Here is the code (snippet) of what I have so far.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
          dashboardBody(
      tabBox(
        id = 'tabset1',
        width = '100%',
        tabPanel('Enter weights', 
                  splitLayout(uiOutput('type'), uiOutput('weight'))),
        tabPanel('Grades Graph', plotOutput('individualGraph')),
        tabPanel('Grades Table', dataTableOutput('summaryDT')),
        tabPanel('Summary by Unit', plotOutput('summaryBarGraph'), br(), dataTableOutput('summaryUnitDT')),
        tabPanel('Class Averages', plotOutput('classAverageGraph'), br(), dataTableOutput('classAverageTable'))
      )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$type <- renderUI({
    df <- data.frame(grades())
    choices <- unique(pull(df, Type))
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'typeVar',
                label = 'Select Type',
                choices = choices,
                selected = choices)
  })

  output$weight <- renderUI({
    numericInput(inputId = 'weightVar',
                 label = 'Select Weight %', value = 50,
                 width = 50)
  })
}
```

Any help/guidance would be appreciated! If I'm wrong in thinking this is the best way to achieve what I want please let me know. I'm open to more suggestions.

Comment: Are the number of homework types fixed, or does this need to be dynamic as well?

Comment: It also has to be dynamic. I've got it working with the number of types of homework dynamic with fixed values of the weight in the spreadsheet. So they can change dependent on spreadsheet. However, if possible, I'd like to make the weight an option to edit in the program instead of updating the spreadsheet. The more I think about it though, it seems less important. If there's not a simple solution I think I'll just leave it out. It's just for a personal project anyway and I wanted to see all what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, does the checkboxGroupInput() make sense here? This seems like the radio buttons UI element match what you're trying to do better (because radio buttons imply to the user that only one can be checked at a time). Second, instead of having many numericInputs created dynamically, could you try to use one numeric input and use updateNumericInput() to change it whenever the radio button changes? Then in your handling of the number change your conditional statement would just need to look at the number AND what radio button is checked.

I'm envisioning something like this:

```
observeEvent(input$RadioButton, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "NumericInputName", value=theVariable)
}
```

where theVariable is the value previously entered for that category (test, quiz, etc), or 0 if nothing has ever been entered for that category.

Comment: I think the checkbox does make sense. So, ultimately, I plan on using this when I start teaching next week. I'd like to be able to view the graphs however I wish with the ease of a button. I'm doing the same thing with different units as well (Intro to biology, cells, biochemistry, etc) so it's easy to see and also show the students where their strengths are and where they may need to focus on studying more. There will be more than just three types of grades as well, such as attendance, extra credit, labs, and so forth, which is why I need it dynamic.

Comment: The radio button is a great suggestion though. I bet I can use that technique for future projects. So thank you for that.

Comment: I guess I'm confused what you want the result to be if multiple boxes are checked. Do you want multiple "Select weight" elements to stack on top of each other?

Comment: No, I wanted them next to it so it would be easy to put them together. But I figured out a different way. I can make the a table editable and pull the calculations from there. This also makes the program easier to use.